# Populating data on drop-down list in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to Load data from `Category` table into a Bootstrap Drop down list like:

```
  <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sel1"></label>
            <select class="form-control" id="cat">
                <option>Select From The List</option>
                @{
                    DataEntities ctx = new DataEntities();
                    var cat = ctx.Categories.OrderByDescending(p => p.CategoryName);
                    foreach (var item in cat)
                    {
                        <option>item</option>
                    }
                }
            </select>
        </div>
```

but I am getting this is result

[image]

the count of `item` is equal to number of rows in `Category` table but I am not getting the actual value! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an `@` symbol in your option tag.

```
foreach (var item in cat)
{
    <option>@item</option>
}
```

In your code, you're just adding the string `"item"` for each item in `cat`.

Comment: I also want to add that those missing `@`'s like this get me way more often than they should, heh.

Comment: @Mona Coder You should also consider adding values to your options `<option value="@item">@item</option>`